# How can I get the video source URL with youtube_dl?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am building a small web application that gets the source url of a YouTube video.
I looked at Reddit, StackOverflow, etc. and found nothing about this.

I want the video source url to be in a string. I looked at the developer documentation of youtube_dl, but there is not option for getting the source. It is important that I cannot execute this in a terminal as it will be on a web server. I am using Python. For the backend of the site Flask.

My code:

```
requested_type = request.args.get("type")
        print(requested_type)

if requested_type == "video":
        media = str(media_url)
        ydl_opts = {}
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([media])
        
        return render_template(
            "warnings/download-started.html",
        )

    elif requested_type == "audio":
        media = str(media_url)
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'keepvideo': False,
        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([media])



        return render_template(
            "warnings/download-started.html",
        )
```

I'm a beginner, so please explain everything as if I were 5. Thank you in advance!

P.S.: I know I use `ydl.download([media])`, it's temporary.

Comment: "It is important that I cannot execute this in a terminal as it will be on a web server."... can you clarify what this means?

Comment: As far as I know it is not safe to execute commands like these, but if I am wrong feel free to tell me.